# How to get all traffic signals from a road segment using overpass turbo?

Tags: openstreetmap, overpass-turbo

I'm working on this road segment 156810827:
https://www.openstreetmap.org/way/156810827#map=15/46.8009/-71.2404

So I need to get all traffic signals from it

Tried this:

```
[out:json];
way(156810827);
node[highway=traffic_signals];
out;
```

but its not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I found:

```xml
<!-- Only select the type of ways you are interested in -->
<query type="way" into="relevant_ways">
 <id-query ref="156810827" type="way"/>
</query>

<!-- Now find all intersection nodes for each way independently -->
<foreach from="relevant_ways" into="this_way">  

  <!-- Get all ways which are linked to this way -->
  <recurse from="this_way" type="way-node" into="this_ways_nodes"/>
  <recurse from="this_ways_nodes" type="node-way" into="linked_ways"/>
  <!-- Again, only select the ways you are interested in, see beginning -->
  <query type="way" into="linked_ways">
    <item set="linked_ways"/>
    <has-kv k="highway"/>
    <has-kv k="highway" modv="not" regv="footway|cycleway|path|service|track"/>
  </query>

  <!-- Get all linked ways without the current way --> 
  <difference into="linked_ways_only">
    <item set="linked_ways"/>
    <item set="this_way"/>
  </difference>
  <recurse from="linked_ways_only" type="way-node" into="linked_ways_only_nodes"/>

  <!-- Return all intersection nodes -->
  <query type="node">
    <item set="linked_ways_only_nodes"/>
    <item set="this_ways_nodes"/>
  </query>
  <print/>
</foreach>
```

It gives all the intersections o the road, the nodes are taged, so u can get trafic signals by tags